# Is there a kind of static print in D?

Tags: compiler-errors, d, compiler-warnings

We do have static branching and traits along with a contract programming features on the other. Contracts are great because of the assert feature of delivering the proper message. And static checking doesn't bring any overhead to a compiled code. So naturally it would be very helpful to have a feature for giving proper error messages in a compile time.

For instance, when one tries to get a cross product of a vector and a differential 1-form with my function, with asserts I can specifically tell him about the issue in terms of domain, not about how the compiler sees it in terms of structures and arrays. Or I can just narrow down function arguments types statically but then the user would have to deal with compiler messages, not mine.

So, the question is: is there some way to print custom messages while compile time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can emit custom messages using several ways:

1. `pragma(msg, message)` will evaluate the `message` expression and print the result during compilation.
2. `static assert(expression, message)` will cause compilation to be aborted when `expression`, which is evaluated at compile-time, is false. This is the D equivalent of the C `#error` preprocessor directive.
3. During CTFE (Compile-Time Function Execution), uncaught exceptions and assert failures will act as a compile-time error, and emit the attached message as well.
4. The `deprecated` keyword can now have an explanation message.
5. There is currently no way to print an evaluated expression during CTFE interpretation, although `ctfeWriteln` is proposed as a `writeln` variant which works during CTFE interpretation.